# javascript dynamically adding option to select inexplicably causes duplicate set of options

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

I'm try to create a dropdown multi-select menu in a table cell using vanilla javascript. Somehow I've managed to create a duplicate set of options in the process which you can see in the console if you run the code. Perhaps what I'm doing is the wrong approach. Any advice would be appreciated.

```js
let allrooms = ['entry', 'kitchen', 'bath', 'hall', 'bed', 'garage'];
let selectedrooms = ['bath', 'kitchen', 'garage'];

let menuHeader = document.getElementById('menu-header');
let roomcontainer = document.getElementById('menu-roomcontainer');

// set the menu header (also a 'td') to a comma delimited string 
function addRoomNamesToMenuHeader() {
  menuHeader.childNodes[0].nodeValue = selectedrooms.toString();
}

// create and append options to a 'select' from a string array
(function addProjectRoomsToMenu() {
  addRoomNamesToMenuHeader();
  let str = 'added elements: '
  for (let r of allrooms) {
    let newroom = document.createElement('option');
    newroom.innerHTML = '<option value="' + r + '" class="devroom">' + r + '</option>';
    roomcontainer.appendChild(newroom);
    if (selectedrooms.indexOf(r) > -1) {
      newroom.selected = 'selected';
    }
    str += (roomcontainer.children.length + ' ' + r + '  ');
  }
  console.log(str);

  let list = document.querySelectorAll('option');
  str = 'NOTE DUPLICATES: option list =\n';
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    str += ('\t' + i + ' ' + list[i].label + ' ' + list[i].selected + ' ');
    if (i & 1) {
      str += '\n';
    }
  }
  console.log(str);

  let selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    roomcontainer.querySelectorAll('option option[selected]'), [
      function(o) {
        return o.value;
      }
    ]
  );
  console.log('NOTE EMPTY QUERY FOR "option option[selected]"=' + selected);
})();

// changes in option selections will result in a change to
// 'selectedrooms' and menuheader
roomcontainer.onchange = function(e) {
  let selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    roomcontainer.querySelectorAll('option option[selected]'), [
      function(o) {
        return o.value;
      }
    ]
  );
  console.log('NOTE EMPTY LIST selected "option"=' + selected);

  selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    roomcontainer.querySelectorAll('option'), [
      function(o) {
        return o.value;
      }
    ]
  );
  console.log('NOTE DUPLICATES IN LIST all "option"=' + selected);

  // TODO: KLUDGE WORK-AROUND
  selectedrooms.length = 0;
  let list = document.querySelectorAll('option');
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].selected) {
      selectedrooms.push(list[i].label);
    }
  }
  addRoomNamesToMenuHeader();
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  let target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);

  if (target === menuHeader && roomcontainer.style.display == "none") {
    roomcontainer.style.display = "block";
  } else if (target.parentNode !== roomcontainer) {
    roomcontainer.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#menu-roomcontainer,
#menu-header,
table {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  max-width: 14em;
  min-width: 14em;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
/*prevent pushing down subsequent rows*/

#menu-roomcontainer {
  position: absolute;
}
/*prevent empty cell from collapsing*/

tr:before {
  content: '\a0';
}
#menu-header {
  color: blue;
}
option {
  color: darkolivegreen;
}
option:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}
option:checked {
  background: lightseagreen;
}
option,
#menu-header:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
option,
td {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='menu-header'>
      <select multiple id='menu-roomcontainer' style='display: none;'></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you cut down your code to just the segment that has the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
newroom.innerHTML = '<option value="' + r + '" class="devroom">' + r + '</option>';
```

`newroom` is already an `<option>` element, so you're creating an option inside an option, which is invalid. It should be:

```
newroom.value = r;
newroom.className = 'devroom';
newroom.innerHTML = r;
```

```js
let allrooms = ['entry', 'kitchen', 'bath', 'hall', 'bed', 'garage'];
let selectedrooms = ['bath', 'kitchen', 'garage'];

let menuHeader = document.getElementById('menu-header');
let roomcontainer = document.getElementById('menu-roomcontainer');

// set the menu header (also a 'td') to a comma delimited string 
function addRoomNamesToMenuHeader() {
  menuHeader.childNodes[0].nodeValue = selectedrooms.toString();
}

// create and append options to a 'select' from a string array
(function addProjectRoomsToMenu() {
  addRoomNamesToMenuHeader();
  let str = 'added elements: '
  for (let r of allrooms) {
    let newroom = document.createElement('option');
    newroom.value = r;
    newroom.className = 'devroom';
    newroom.innerHTML = r;
    roomcontainer.appendChild(newroom);
    if (selectedrooms.indexOf(r) > -1) {
      newroom.selected = 'selected';
    }
    str += (roomcontainer.children.length + ' ' + r + '  ');
  }
  console.log(str);

  let list = document.querySelectorAll('option');
  str = 'NOTE DUPLICATES: option list =\n';
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    str += ('\t' + i + ' ' + list[i].label + ' ' + list[i].selected + ' ');
    if (i & 1) {
      str += '\n';
    }
  }
  console.log(str);

  let selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    roomcontainer.querySelectorAll('option option[selected]'), [
      function(o) {
        return o.value;
      }
    ]
  );
  console.log('NOTE EMPTY QUERY FOR "option option[selected]"=' + selected);
})();

// changes in option selections will result in a change to
// 'selectedrooms' and menuheader
roomcontainer.onchange = function(e) {
  let selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    roomcontainer.querySelectorAll('option option[selected]'), [
      function(o) {
        return o.value;
      }
    ]
  );
  console.log('NOTE EMPTY LIST selected "option"=' + selected);

  selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    roomcontainer.querySelectorAll('option'), [
      function(o) {
        return o.value;
      }
    ]
  );
  console.log('NOTE DUPLICATES IN LIST all "option"=' + selected);

  // TODO: KLUDGE WORK-AROUND
  selectedrooms.length = 0;
  let list = document.querySelectorAll('option');
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].selected) {
      selectedrooms.push(list[i].label);
    }
  }
  addRoomNamesToMenuHeader();
}

document.onclick = function(e) {
  let target = (e && e.target) || (event && event.srcElement);

  if (target === menuHeader && roomcontainer.style.display == "none") {
    roomcontainer.style.display = "block";
  } else if (target.parentNode !== roomcontainer) {
    roomcontainer.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#menu-roomcontainer,
#menu-header,
table {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  max-width: 14em;
  min-width: 14em;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
/*prevent pushing down subsequent rows*/

#menu-roomcontainer {
  position: absolute;
}
/*prevent empty cell from collapsing*/

tr:before {
  content: '\a0';
}
#menu-header {
  color: blue;
}
option {
  color: darkolivegreen;
}
option:hover {
  background: lightgray;
}
option:checked {
  background: lightseagreen;
}
option,
#menu-header:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
option,
td {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='menu-header'>
      <select multiple id='menu-roomcontainer' style='display: none;'></select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry, for not acknowledging earlier. I thought I'd get an email notification at my regular email address. Also, I've since decided this would be better using UL instead of SELECT since the Control Key/Shift Key thing would preclude mobile use,